# Windows Forms YesNo Message Box - Buttons Text

Tags: winforms, messagebox

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to change button text for Yes & No buttons on MessageBox.Show Dialog?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4264664/how-to-change-button-text-for-yes-no-buttons-on-messagebox-show-dialog)

In a Windows Forms application I have a MessageBox with YesNo buttons. I want to change the text on the buttons (from "Yes", "No" to something custom).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I were you I'd create my own MessageBox dialog.  It's not that hard and I'm sure you'd be able to do this faster than hacking the standard MessageBox.

Answer (score 0):

Your only possible "customization" with the winforms MessageBox is to use the [MessageBoxButton](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.messageboxbutton.aspx) enumeration when creating the MessageBox.

It is fairly limited, so looking for a third party message box or creating your own dialog box may be a better choice.