# Where are win form’s default MessageBoxIcons located?

Tags: winforms, messagebox

I am trying to create a custom message box. I followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4264664/how-to-change-the-button-text-for-yes-and-no-buttons-in-the-messagebox-show) question’s answer. I want to add an ability to add a MessageBoxIcon just like in the default `MessageBox`. I’ve added a `PictureBox` but what location do I browse to use those default icons (warning, error, stop, info etc)?

Comment: In a quick and dirty search I found that some are within shell32.dll, as icon resources. Still haven't found all of them, but that library seems like a good starting point.

Comment: Check out [`SystemIcons`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.systemicons?view=netframework-4.7.2) class

Comment: MessageBox is not implemented in .NET, it is merely a wrapper for [the OS function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-messagebox).   Those icons used to be stored in user32.dll, but it got convoluted in recent Windows versions that support MUI resources.  Yes, use the SystemIcons class.

Comment: thank-you guys. It seems like an duplicate to the question you pointed out.

Comment: For others who may run into this problem in the future, just need to do pictureBox1.Image = SystemIcons.Warning.ToBitmap();